# How can I troubleshoot KRFB crashing on start?

Tags: debian, kde

I'm using Debian Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l, according to /etc/issue) and KDE 5.14.5 (64 bit) and KRFB 5.0. Last week I set up KRFB and was using it to connect to this Debian system from my iMac. It was easy to setup and worked find and I was happy and the universe was beautiful.

Without rebooting or manually updating anything on my Linux system (but rebooting the iMac a few times during updates), today I tried to connect to the Linux system remotely and it wouldn't work. I used ssh to connect and did `ps aux|grep krfb` and there is a task running, but I can't connect from the iMac.

I've tried running KRFB from the menu and it won't run - it starts and stops. No window, no information at all. I tried running KRFB from the command line. It starts and exits. No error messages.

While I suspect there may be issues on my iMac, at this point, I'm addressing the issue on my Debian system.

How can I find out why KRFB starts and exits and does not give me the control panel or give me any errors? I'm sure there are logs somewhere of what's going on. I even used apt-get to uninstall and reinstall, with no difference.

Comment: Launch `konsole`, type `killall -9 krfb`, then type `krfb` and check for any error messages on the screen.

Comment: Okay, it started. What's odd is that whatever was wrong survived a reboot. (I don't like rebooting to solve issues, but I had to get something working.) Side note that in Debian, now, for some reason unknown to mortals, there is no killall, only killall5, which kills almost everything running. I had figured since I got nothing from running it from the Konsole before, that was an overall issue (no command line output). If you want to write this up as an answer, I'll upvote and select it. (And note I had to use killall -9 <pid number> to get it to work.)

Comment: `killall` is available in Debian AFAIK - it's in the `psmisc` package. `killall5` is a deprecated utility from the ` sysvinit-utils` package :-)

Comment: Thanks. I had searched with apt-cache and it didn't mention psmisc - wanna bet when I did that, I had a typo?